# Displaying content of highest value in shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

Record.txt has the following information

```
Nosi IT 3000
David HR 4000
```

How can display name an salary of highest paid employee using awk or any other tool that may work. 
if they are stored in records.txt. I want it to display David 4000

Answer (score 1):

Using the always-handy GNU [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -Wf max 6 < record.txt | cut -f 4,6
David   4000
```

Use `datamash` to print out the line with the highest value in the 6th column, and `cut` to get just the columns you care about.

Answer (score 1):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) version:

```
awk 'NF && $3>max {max=$3; id=$1} END {print id" "max}' records.txt
```

This reads as: "In lines with fields (=not empty), if the salary is higher than the current stored maximum (default 0), then update the stored maximum value and the name of the champion. When all lines are processed (= `END`), dump out both variables containing ID and salary.

For reasons of speed I would probably choose this approach with [sort](/questions/tagged/sort) though:

```
sort -k 3 -n -r records.txt | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `awk`, the following should work for the sample input you provided:

```
awk 'NF==0 {next} !name {max=$3; name=$1} {if ($3>max) {max=$3; name=$1};} END{printf("%s : %d\n",name,max)}' records.txt
```

It will skip empty lines and initialize the maximum value `max` and the corresponding name with the data from the first non-empty line (indicated by the `name` variable being `0`, i.e. uninitialized if one expects a string here). It will replace them with the corresponding values of later (non-empty) lines if the salary encountered is greater then the current `max`. In the end, it prints name and value.

**An even shorter version**, as suggested by Stephen Kitt and Alex Stragies:

```
awk 'NF>0 && (!name || $3>max) {max=$3; name=$1} END {printf("%s : %d\n",name,max);}' records.txt
```

This makes use of the fact that setting `max` and `name` is the same for the first non-empty line and every line with column 3 value greater then `max`, and so the same action block can be used by checking if either of the two cases applies. And skipping empty lines can simply be incorporated, too, by demanding `NF>0` as a precondition to do anything in the first place.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, that does make it more compact! I will include it in the answer.

Comment: @StephenKitt As to why I didn't completely include it: although it fully works in the current example where all numbers are positive, in the more general case of "finding the highest value in column 3" where numbers can be negative and the highest value actually 0, it may miss that highest value if empty lines are present. This is rather far-fetched, I agree, but I tried to make it as generally applicable as I could imagine.

Comment: Indeed, if the maximum can be negative or nil, the short version doesn’t work and there has to be a distinction between “0” and “no value”.

Comment: the call to `next` can be golfed here in this specific case, just `NF&&(!name||$3>max){....}`. I used that in my answer as an alternative to the `sort | head` solution.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to convert it to 3-column format and then sort based on salary column.

```
$ cat file
Nosi IT 3000 David HR 4000 John Security 3500 George Finance 3700

$ awk -v RS='[ \n]' '{a=$0;getline b; getline c; print a,c}'  file | sort -rnk2 | head -1
David 4000
```

Comment: This outputs `David` as he's first in alphabet, not highest paid.

Comment: @RudiC, thanks I edited and added sort options.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sort -k3,3rn file | head -n 1
David HR 4000
```

This sorts the file numerically on the 3rd column in decreasing order, then picks out first line of that result using `head`.

If the file has tabs as field delimiters, use `-t $'\t'` with `sort`.  That way, you would also be able to have fields with spaces in them.

To only display the name and the salary, use `awk '{ print $1,$3; exit }'` instead of `head -n 1`.